# If a sequence is increasing, then the series is always divergent?

Tags: real-analysis

I wanted to know if the above statement is true. If not, please provide a counter-example. If true, please provide a proof.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try at all?  lol

Comment: You should share your thoughts on the problem.

Comment: What "series?"  How does the increasing sequence relate to the series?

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$a_n=-\frac{1}{2^n}$$ as a counterexample.

Clearly,
$$a_n\lt a_{n+1}$$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$.

Moreover,
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n=-1$$

Answer (score 1):

If the terms of the sequence are eventually positive, the corresponding series is necessarily divergent. If not, it need not be. You might have $a_n=-2^{-n}$, for instance; clearly the sequence $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is increasing, but the series is just a geometric series with ratio $\frac12$, so

$$\sum_{n\ge 0}-2^{-n}=\frac{-1}{1-\frac12}=-2\;.$$